# BASH - Taking next element in for loop with file names

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to compare the differences between all pairs of files. However, in order to compare pairs of files, I need to be able to access the element after the current element in the for loop. This is the code I have currently -

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find -type f); do
   b = $(file+1) -- I know this is not the correct way to access the next element
   diff $(file) $(b) >/dev/null
   if [ #? -eq 0 ]
      echo $(file) and $(b) are the same
   else
      echo $(file) and $(b) are not the same
   fi
done
```

Any assistance with a way of accessing the next element would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the previous element instead of the next: store the current file name of an iteration and reuse it in the next one. Something like:

```
#!/usr/env/bin bash

declare previous=""

for file in $(find -type f); do
  if [[ -n $previous ]]; then
    if diff --brief "${previous}" "${file}" > /dev/null; then
      echo "${previous} and ${file} are the same"
    else
      echo "${previous} and ${file} are not the same"
    fi
  fi
  previous="${file}"
done
```

Note: if you really want to enclose variable names, use the curly braces (as in the code above), not the parentheses (as in your code): `${file}` evaluates as the value of variable `file` while `$(file)` calls command `file` without an argument, and returns an error message.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly :) Thanks so much. Also regarding the curly braces vs parentheses, I realised that after submitting - I didn't copy the text over from the terminal correctly. Thanks again!